# Why isn't Eclipse CDT adding a comment after closing namespace braces?

Tags: namespaces, eclipse-cdt, code-completion, eclipse-mars, autocommenting

I'm using Eclipse CDT Mars.1 (4.5.1) to write some C++ code.

When I type in `namespace foo {`, Eclipse completes this with the closing namespace brace, two lines below. Now, I also want a comment on that closing brace, i.e.

```
namespace foo {

} /* namespace foo */
```

I know that Eclipse *is* supposed to add this comment, since I saw it in the preferences - under **Window > Preferences > C/C++ > Code Style > Code Templates > Code > End of namespace declaration**. It's just not getting used! Why?

PS - If it matters, I'm running Debian Stretch but I downloaded my Eclipse directly from eclipse.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CDT does not support automatically adding the closing comment on the namespace just as a side-effect of automatically inserting the closing brace `}`.

The best way to get the closing comment automatically is to type only `namespace` and then auto-complete (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>).

**More Details**

There are three different features here.

1. *Automatically close* of *{Braces}* settable in *Preferences* -> *C/C++* -> *Editor* -> *Typing*

   This feature simply puts a closing brace when you type an open brace and is what you are doing when you type `namespace foo {`
2. File template, settable in *Preferences* > *C/C++* > *Code Style* > *Code Templates* > *Code* > *End of namespace declaration* (and *Beginning of namespace declaration*)

   This controls the format of new classes in new files that you create with the new *Class Wizard*. This is the setting you have referred to in your question.
3. Editor templates, settable in *Preferences* -> *C/C++* -> *Editor* -> *Templates* -> *namespace*

   This feature works when you insert a `namespace` template. To do that:

   1. type `namespace` or part of it
   2. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. This will bring you the standard completion proposals.

   [image: namespace proposals]

   3. Select the `namespace` entry on the list corresponding to the template version
   4. Type your namespace name and you should see it appearing in the declaration and the comment at the end

[image: typing with two cursors]

Note: If you type `namespace` completely and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> it will probably auto-select the template if there are no other possible matches.